# Wrong variance for sub-images in python

Tags: python, split, variance

I'm trying to calculate for each subimage (square) the variance, and I can't understand something.
Here is the variance for each square for the first line :

[array([[0.]]), array([[12594.46370602]]), array([[14952.43356228]]), array([[1968.53027344]]), array([[1968.53027344]]), array([[1968.53027344]]), array([[1968.53027344]]), array([[13495.383811]]), array([[0.]]), array([[10932.52408504]]), array([[1968.53027344]]), array([[1968.53027344]]), array([[1968.53027344]]), array([[1968.53027344]]), array([[1968.53027344]]),array([[1968.53027344]])

I agree that because of the formula when i get a black square, I have a null variance, because every pixel worths 0 in the square and the mean of the square too, quite logical. But I got 1968.53027344 for white pixels, whereas it is clear there is no variance all the square is white, and because of the formula, every pixel in this square worths 255, as it is a grayscale image, and so the mean also, so I should have 0, right ?

Here is the code :

```
im =  cv2.imread('path.png', 0)
imgheight=im.shape[0]
imgwidth=im.shape[1]

y1 = 0
M = imgheight//16
N = imgwidth//16

v=[]

for y in range(0,imgheight,M):
    for x in range(0, imgwidth, N):
        y1 = y + M
        x1 = x + N
        tiles = im[y:y+M,x:x+N]
        std=cv2.meanStdDev(tiles)[1]
        std=std*std
        v.append(std)

        cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x1, y1), (0, 255, 0))
        cv2.imwrite("save/" + str(x) + '_' + str(y)+".png",tiles)

cv2.imwrite("pic.png",im)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're adding a black grid around the tile which then is used in the calculation for the next tile.
Also, I changed your standard deviation calculation, it may work with meanStdDev if you want to stick with that

This worked for me:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
im =  cv2.imread('path.png', 0)
imgheight=im.shape[0]
imgwidth=im.shape[1]

y1 = 0
M = imgheight//16
N = imgwidth//16

v=[]

for y in range(0,imgheight,M):
    for x in range(0, imgwidth, N):
        y1 = y + M
        x1 = x + N
        tiles = im[y:y+M,x:x+N]
        std=np.std(tiles)
        std=std*std
        v.append(std)

for y in range(0,imgheight,M):
    for x in range(0, imgwidth, N):
        y1 = y + M
        x1 = x + N
        tiles = im[y:y+M,x:x+N]
        cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x1, y1), (0, 255, 0))
        cv2.imwrite("save/" + str(x) + '_' + str(y)+".png",tiles)

cv2.imwrite("pic.png",im)
```

I think you could also do this to avoid multiple loops:

```
im =  cv2.imread('path.png', 0)
imgheight=im.shape[0]
imgwidth=im.shape[1]

y1 = 0
M = imgheight//16
N = imgwidth//16

v=[]

for y in range(0,imgheight,M):
    for x in range(0, imgwidth, N):
        y1 = y + M
        x1 = x + N
        tiles = im[y:y+M,x:x+N]
        std=cv2.meanStdDev(tiles)[1]
        std=std*std
        v.append(std)

        cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x1 - 1, y1 - 1), (0, 255, 0))
        cv2.imwrite("save/" + str(x) + '_' + str(y)+".png",tiles)
cv2.imwrite("pic.png",im)
```

Comment: Of course yes, thanks a lot, I didn't think this could impact that much

Comment: No worries. I've added a second option to move the grid up and left a single pixel so you can do it all in one without an impact

Comment: Wow, you rock ! Thanks again